# Calling Ajax repeatedly after specific time using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Searched on jquery timer functions but i need a solution to call the below ajax function every 5 minutes using jquery..

```
    $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '<?php echo base_url().'index.php/score-refresh/scorecard';?>',
  success: function(html){
    $('.score_news').append(html);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it using a `setInterval` call like this

```
var timer, delay = 300000; //5 minutes counted in milliseconds.

timer = setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '<?php echo base_url().'index.php/score-refresh/scorecard';?>',
      success: function(html){
        $('.score_news').append(html);
      }
    });
}, delay);
```

if you need it to stop at some point call

```
clearInterval(timer);
```

Comment: The contents are getting appended how to get it replaced instead of the old content once the function refreshes ..?

Comment: use `.html` instead of `.append`

Comment: how can i pass an argument  to this type of ajax